# ASP.NET Core CSV text output formatter using CsvHelper

Tags: csv, asp.net-core

I'm looking to write custom ASP.NET Core `TextOutputFormatter` so I can throw any IEnumerable as an action result and it will produce comma separated list as an output. I don't want to save the results to a file or anything like it, just serve it as a response directly. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) seems to be very intuitive to use but I don't know how to write to response body. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
        Encoding = selectedEncoding,
    };

    if (context.Object is IEnumerable<object> list)
    {
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(response.Body);
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config);
        await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(list); // does not work
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

When I replace

```
using var writer = new StreamWriter(response.Body);
```

with

```
StringBuilder sb = new();
using var writer = new StringWriter(sb);
```

I can see my `sb` is being built just as expected so it's not a problem with my `IEnumerable<object>` or with `CsvWriter`. I just don't know how to write results it produce to `HttpContext.Response.Body`

Comment: Do you mean that the files generated by CsvHelper are not saved locally, but are opened directly in the response?

Comment: Yes, I want to put csv-formatted data in the response body just like json for example

Comment: Do the items of the IEnumerable have a ToString method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I did not explicitly override ToString() but like every object they do have ToString() method i.e. list.ElementAt(0).ToString() returns
"DataModels.Models.MyItem"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be the best answer, but I was able to make this work using `StringBuilder` and replacing `StreamWriter` with `StringWriter`

```
public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
        Encoding = selectedEncoding,
            
    };

    if (context.Object is IEnumerable<object> list)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();

        using var writer = new StringWriter(sb);
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config);
        await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(list);

        await response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString(), selectedEncoding);
    }
}
```

`WriteAsync` requires adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace